# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'M'

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding

I am getting this exception at runtime which says it cannot find a column 'M' in datasource, but i am not using 'M' anywhere. I am trying to bind data to dropdownlist inside gridview.
I need to do this in .aspx page rather than code behind.
Here's the code i am using:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDrpDownlistSample" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="sqlDS1">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name").ToString()%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Logged In Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("LoggedIn") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sex">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drpSex" DataSourceID="sqlDS1" runat="server" DataTextField='<%# Eval("Sex") %>'  DataValueField='<%# Eval("id") %>' ></asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>


    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDS1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select * from Users"> </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I have got this working by removing Eval from dropdownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now.
I have got this working by removing Eval from dropdownlist, as it was expecting just the column name not the Eval expression.